# Showing text in EditView on right side

Tags: android

I am developing an app for RTL locale. I have a problem to show the hint in the AutoCompleteTextView on the right side. But the String shows on the right side.But if I add gravity=right,the hint String shows on the right side but then the string on the AutoCompleteTextView is displayed on the left side. i dont know how to solve this issue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/supplierNameTV"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierName_CB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/supplierNameTV"/>
```

Comment: can not understand what u are trying to say!!

Comment: Have you tried with singleLine="true" and ellipsize="end" on your AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: @Ankit,which part you did not understand.

Comment: @Slickelito what will this do

Comment: i dit not get what exactly u want.. can u add screen shot

Comment: i tried something like this but no luck `<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/cusName_CB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right"/>`

Comment: capture screen shot of ur emulator, Edit ur question there is an option for adding Image, u can post it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like below image, Let me know how exactly do you want it to look like, find code below the image ...

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="right">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asdbakdsn"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierName_CB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="adsas"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the difference is that you are typing english character,replace that to persian/farsi text and add a hint to it also.then load it and you will see what i mean. what you have done now is added gravity=right,which shows the text to the right. But in my case when i add gravity= right the hint string shows to the right side but when i select a string from the autocomplete widget the string show to the left. then when i remove the gravity=right,the hint shows to the left but the autocomplete string i select is shown to the right.hope i made myself clear

Comment: I tried your code,but it did not work. I mean the hint text is shown on the right side of the AutoComplete widget but when i select a name from the AutoComplete,the name is left aligned not right aligned like it shows for the hint string.